# I need to access event context AND object context in event handler

Tags: javascript, events, scope, this

I've this piece of code:

```
function ActivityDialog(_divId, _title) {

    function addButton() {
      var buttonElement = document.createElement('input');
      buttonElement.setAttribute('type','button');
      buttonElement.setAttribute('class','button');
      buttonElement.setAttribute('id','updateButton-' + id););
      buttonElement.onclick = this.updateAction;
    };

    function updateAction() {
      var buttonId = this.id; // correct: this is the Button
      this.sendUpdateRequest(stringUrl); // not defined: Need to reference the current ActivityDialog!!!    
    };

    function sendUpdateRequest(url) {
      // something...
    };

}
```

As you can see the problem is when I call function `sendUpdateRequest;` how can I, at the same time, retrieve button infos and call a function?

Comment: http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript I hope this paper will help

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal he's having a scoping issue where he's trying to reference the event context with `this` (Button) and the Object context (ActivityDialog) within an event handler.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: It'd be much clearer if the whole thing about "buttons" and "activities" were abstracted away. Meanwhile, he uses `this` on one line then again on the next in the same scope, but complains that one of these usages evaluates to something he's not expecting? That makes no sense.

Comment: Probably because he doesn't understand something... how dare he ask a question about something he doesn't understand... oh wait... where are we again?

Answer (score 1):

You might try this...

```
function ActivityDialog(_divId, _title) {

    // Store the ActivityDialog context
    var self = this;

    function addButton() {
      var buttonElement = document.createElement('input');
      buttonElement.setAttribute('type','button');
      buttonElement.setAttribute('class','button');
      buttonElement.setAttribute('id','updateButton-' + id););
      buttonElement.onclick = this.updateAction;
    };

    function updateAction() {
      var buttonId = this.id;
      self.sendUpdateRequest(stringUrl); // <--------------------- 
    };

    function sendUpdateRequest(url) {
      // something...
    };

}
```

Because your using `updateAction` as a event handler, you correctly see that `this` will be the button that generates the event.  Storing the initial context of the `ActivityDialog` will allow you to maintain access to it even within event handlers.

Comment: unfortunately, i've already the problem:sendUpdateRequest is not defined. stringurl is correctly valued (i'm using firebug for debugging).. the button creation happens in a function defined in object ActivityDialog. i need to refer to sendUpdareRequest that is another ActivityDialog function..